# Flutter Clip Path

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-clippath

Logo I want to create with clippath

[Logo I want to create with clippath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyRo1.png)

I tried to make the logo above but it didn't work. How to do it properly?

This is what i made with clippath,stack,Transform.rotate and positioned widgets and clip path.
I dont have permission to put whole code

[Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXqxt.png)

Clip Path:

```
class MyClipper  extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 150);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height - 150);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height );
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand how to do this image
White space only i want to draw but i dont know how to do
[image: ClipPath]

Comment: It looks like you need more splines around the ends.  However we're programmers here and not graphic designers.  My recommendation would be to open the image in an illustrating program and vectorize it and take the resulting path as a starting point for making your own.

Comment: Thay make sense but i'll try to do it with adobe xd